# Camel how do I add an authorisation header to a rest route?

Tags: java, apache-camel, jwt, authorization, token

I'm attempting to add an authorisation header to my camel rest route. Here's the route:

```
    restConfiguration().producerComponent("http4").host(env.getProperty("my.rest.host"));
    from(env.getProperty("in.route"))
            .to(env.getProperty("rest.endpoint.path"))
```

I'm familiar with the 'non-camel' procedure, for example using RestTemplate where you can do something like setHeader("Authorisation", "Bearer myJWT..."). I was expecting there to be something equally as straightforward for camel. But my search so far has not prevailed! Can anybody give me a hint?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use exchage and update header

```
 from(env.getProperty("in.route")).process(new  Processor {
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        //you token logic
        String token = "--token logic-------"
        exchange.getIn().setHeader("Authorization", token)

    }
}).to(env.getProperty("rest.endpoint.path"))
```

Comment: Thanks, by the way for Bearer Token JWT type authorisation would that be:   .setHeader("Authorization", constant("Bearer MyToken")) ?

Comment: hi @JohnnyAlpha could I have updated answer please have a look, you can retrieve params from exchange if they are in request